# Set up a number of categories to display on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

I am basically looking for a way to display only 3 categories on my template page.
I used a **foreach loop** to display all the categories on my pages

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . 
    get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name 
  . '</a></div>';
}?>
```

this code displays all the categories on my page but I just want to display 3 per page and eventually add paginations

Comment: why not just return 3 entries in the ``get_categories();`` instead of all of them? or is there a reason you cant? if you cant then you could do a ``I % 3`` and output whenever the condition equals 0

Comment: I don't think if I do that I will be able to add pagination to page for the categories

Comment: I only said to do so as you specified ``eventually add paginations``. if you need to add them right away then you can still do so. just add a param set to the function to query "pages" or return the data as a whole as a multi-object if that makes sense

you should be able to still use the solution I gave to organize that in there function to filter results if needed

Comment: please can you write a small code on how ! should I implement or do that ? pleaase!! @MysticSeagull

Comment: for which @Adrien Duval, the getting 3 or making pagination? cause if making pagination it won't be small and I don't know your data set.

Comment: please first for the number of categories on the page (getting 3 categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my comments above. the code example I can give you is as follows

```php
for($i = 0; $i <= count($categories); $i++) {
    /* 
    Pagination purposes this is how you can format data to an object 
    base.
    */
    if($i % 3 = 0) {
       // add to an array
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
// echo categories HTML but $categories[$i] instead
}
```

though let it be known that this wont fully work as you would think etc... etc... I cant explain the modulus operator in depth as I cant think of an easy way without you trying to learn it so you can understand it well.

this way you are only getting 3

Comment: thanks bro, but is there and easier way to do this am still a fresher trying to build my first wordpress theme and this a little bit complex for me

Comment: None that I can immediately think of in PHP terms. if you need the first 3 then this is how unless you hard code the values. which I don't recommend unless you have the same data/ need to do so

Comment: please help me with a last think,
please implement you code with mine please!

Comment: I essentially did, I even gave you the comment on what you have to change. The second for loop is what you need to change your loop to pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$page=$_GET['page_number']; 

$categories = get_categories();

$data=array_chunk($categories ,3);

$paginations=count($data); // use loop for paginations in html page

foreach($data[$page] as $category) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . 
    get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name 
  . '</a></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$startCategory = 0;
for($i = $startCategory; $i <= count($categories); $i++) {
 echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' .get_category_link($categories[$i]['term_id']) . '">' . $categories[$i]['name']. '</a></div>';
 $startCategory++;
 if($startCategory > (count($categories) -1)){
  break;
 }
//pass $startCategory to next page , next page
$startCategory  = $_POST["startCategory"]; // by using post method

$startCategory  = $_GET["startCategory"]; // by using get method
for($i = $startCategory; $i <= count($categories); $i++) {
echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . 
    get_category_link($categories[$i]['term_id']) . '">' . $categories[$i]['name']
  . '</a></div>';
$startCategory++;
 if($startCategory > (count($categories) -1)){
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).